# Ubuntu installer GRUB can't load on an old pc

Tags: boot, grub2, bios

I am trying to install Ubuntu 22.04.2 on an old PC from 2007.
It has Gigabyte GA-945P-S3 motherboard with "Award Modular BIOS v6.00PG". I created USB(8GB) installer with Rufus(MBR, BIOS or UEFI target system) on my main PC. It loads GRUB perfectly fine there on UEFI BIOS, but on the old computer (I guess it is just BIOS, selecting USB-HDD as boot drive)

```
GRUB
```

is shown with blinking cursor, and that's it. I suppose [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Troubleshooting#GRUB) is the problem that I am facing.

What may cause this problem at what should I try?

Comment: I had an old Gigabyte board from 2006. Took me a  long time to resize it did not boot from any USB device, but USB flash drive was in list of drives or seen as another hard drive. Have you updated to latest available BIOS? It may still be 10 years old but newer than original. I put a tiny 60GB SSD in that old system in 2011 and it became so much better I did not retire it for another 3 years and was still very functional. You do not want Ubuntu but a light weight flavor. https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours
Light weight flavors:
Lubuntu, xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Budgie Or even midweight Kubuntu